# Magento 1.x Default menu not showing

Tags: magento-1.9, menu, header, localhost

Have some problem with default menu on my testing and practice local host. Here is the problem created few just test subcategories and they are not shown at all in case nothing is shown. For this I also create another localhost with sample data and when I created just some page with nothing and add it as subcategory everything went fine page is displayed and link is working fine.

My question is do I need to create all to be root categories or I need to edit some lines in maybe local.xml?

Comment: You need to add sub categories under default category for appearing on front

Comment: everything is done. read my question done this and worked on sample data project but on this clean i dont see this. link and everything else is set to bee seen and yeas on show in menus.

Comment: Problem solved friend told me what to do and this passed. Very stupid problem at the end.

Comment: great, you can put your answer here!